# change colour of title bar in jquery pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Messing about trying to change the background colour of the title bar in a jquery pop to to green (seen as blue in the jsfiddle)...cant seem to get it...any suggestions welcome?

```
    $("#dia").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    title:"Access Point",
    height: 200,
    width: 300,
    modal: false,
    draggable: true,
    position: [900, 150],
    dialogClass: "foo",
    //show: {effect: 'bounce', duration: 350, times: 3}
    show: {effect: 'fade', duration: 2000}
});

$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background-color", "green");
$(".ui-dialog").css("background-color", "green");
$(".ui-dialog-title").css("background-color", "green");
$(".ui-dialog-content").css("background-color", "green");
```

please see http://jsfiddle.net/dEvKb/3254/

Comment: just add $(".ui-widget-header").css("background", "green"); and also remove border

Comment: Just be careful not to get background-color and background confused. Changing one won't necessary change the other.

Answer (score 0):

A gradient is apply in the title bar, it's like a background image, you must reset it.

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background", "green");
```

Or

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css({'background-color': 'green', 'background-image': 'none'});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the default dialog header has a background image. Try changing it to the following code:

```
$(".ui-dialog-title").css("background", "green");
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css({"background": "green", "border": "none"});
```

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dEvKb/3258/

Answer (score 0):

You not need to use `JS` to change background color.

### CSS WAY *(raccomanded)*

```
.ui-widget-header,.ui-dialog-titlebar,.ui-dialog,.ui-dialog-title,.ui-dialog-content{
    background: none green;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dEvKb/3257/

### JS WAY

```
$(".ui-widget-header,.ui-dialog-titlebar,.ui-dialog,.ui-dialog-title,.ui-dialog-content").css("background", "green");
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dEvKb/3259/